# Email statistics Action "Clicked on at least one link" comes two time. Why?

Tags: gui-extensions, outbound-email

I am working on Email tracking then I saw one action comes two times. I do not understand why this one action appears two times. Please help me out with this problem.

[image]

Comment: What version of SDL Tridion are you using?  I had a look on a SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 environment, and I only see this once.

Comment: SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug. If there's a link without a description, it assumes it is the entry for 'Clicked on at least one link'. The description should really be mandatory (or it should use the URL value).

Anyway, I think you can fix this by checking your template for any tracked links that specify an empty description/title and giving it a proper description instead.

Comment: Hi Peter, this action appears two times because of one link has empty href like href="". Thank you so much now its working fine.

Comment: My suspicions confirmed! Glad I could help :)